# Insert [AnyObject] into [NSMutableDictionary]

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to build an app using tableView with two columns (one displaying strings, the other one a CheckBox for each string).
The strings are coming from a [AnyObject] variable.
I have try so many things to insert the result of [AnyObject] into the NsMutableDictionnary (which is used by NsTableView) but none of them works.
I have to build the dic manually with the right number of object (related to the result of [AnyObject]) to make it work but I would like the dic to build itself automatically.

Here is an exemple of the code, working if [AnyObject] is made with 4 elements. The TableView column names are "jobs" and "unload" :

```
import Cocoa
@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate,NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!
var dataArray:[NSMutableDictionary] = [["jobs": "", "unload": 0],["jobs": "", "unload": 0],["jobs": "", "unload": 0],["jobs": "", "unload": 0]];

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
...
...
...
var ctlelems:[AnyObject] = grepOut!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
dataArray = [["jobs": "ctlelems[0]", "unload": 0],["jobs": "ctlelems[1]", "unload": 0],["jobs": "ctlelems[2]", "unload": 0],["jobs": "ctlelems[3]", "unload": 0]];
}
    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    }
    func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return dataArray.count
    }
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject?
    {
        let object = dataArray[row] as NSMutableDictionary
        if ((tableColumn!.identifier) == "unload")
        {
            println(object)
            return object[tableColumn!.identifier] as? Int!
        }
        else
        {

            return object[tableColumn!.identifier] as? String!
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)
    {
        dataArray[row].setObject(object!, forKey: (tableColumn?.identifier)!)
    }
}
```

I would like to do the following,

```
var x: Int = 0
for lines in ctlelems {
            dataArray = [["jobs": ctlelems[x], "unload": 0]];
            x=x+1
        }
```

but it is not working.
Most of the time I get "Found nill" error, or only the last element of [AnyObject] is displayed.
Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataArray = [["jobs": ctlelems[x], "unload": 0]];
```

This means you redefining the `dataArray` with each iteration. You should append to `dataArray` instead.

**Declare and init your `dataArray`:**

```
var dataArray = [Dictionary<String, Any>]()
```

**And append to it:**

```
for line in ctlelems {
    dataArray.append(["jobs": line, "unload": 0])
}
```

or in a more Swifty way:

```
dataArray = ctlelems.map { ["jobs": $0, "unload": 0] }
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful answer. dataArray is now containing all the records (I used the first exemple). But "println(object)" is showing only one record with empty field: :{
  jobs = "";
    unload = 0;
}. I dont know if the dic is declared correctly : var dataArray:[NSMutableDictionary] = [["jobs": "", "unload": 0]];. Is this correct? Why is "object" empty?